# Displacement map on BoxGeometry only moves edges?

Tags: three.js, normals

I'm just starting to get my bearings with threejs and I'm having an issue using Displacement Maps.

http://codepen.io/jpschwinghamer/pen/BWPebJ

I have a simple BoxGeometry that I'm trying to apply textures to a phong material. All seem to work correctly except for the displacement map. I made sure to add segments to the BoxGeometry instantiation. Is there some bit of magic that I'm missing to make my displacement map work correctly?

Consider this code:

```
  var animate, camera, displacement, geometry, light, light1, map, material, mesh, normal, reflection, renderer, roughness, textureLoader;

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.querySelector('canvas'),
    antialiased: true
  });

  renderer.setClearColor(0xfff000);

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);

  window.scene = new THREE.Scene();

  light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);

  scene.add(light);

  light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.6);

  scene.add(light1);

  textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  textureLoader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");

  map = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_COL_2K.jpg");
  normal = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_NRM_2K.jpg");
  roughness = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_GLOSS_2K.jpg");
  reflection = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_REFL_2K.jpg");
  displacement = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_DISP_2K.jpg");

  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10);

  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: map,
    normalMap: normal,
    normalScale: new THREE.Vector2(30, -1),
    roughnessMap: roughness,
    reflectionMap: reflection,
    displacementMap: displacement,
    displacementScale: 1,
    displacementBias: 0
  });

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  mesh.position.set(0, 0, -700);

  scene.add(mesh);

  animate = function() {
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    return renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  animate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your displacement map is that there is very little variation in the shades of grey ([see it here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_DISP_2K.jpg)).
The lowest points should be black and the highest should be white (or the other way around, I forget).
You would also need to have enough verticies for this to affect.

I think though that this map should be assigned to the bump map.
But... you probably don't want to use a bump map and normal map. it's usually one or the other.
But, having a look at the normal map you are loading, it is having no effect because it is all the same color. ([see it here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_NRM_2K.jpg)), so therefore, it's only the bump map that you need.

Also, MeshPhongMaterial does not seem to have `roughnessMap` or `reflectionMap` uniforms/properties, so these are doing nothing.

So basically, you only need to load you map and your displacement map, but put the displacement map on the bump map instead.
Maybe also your roughness image putting it on your specularMap.

EDIT.
Embedding code here does not seem to run because of CORS on the images.
See a [FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/92/)

```
    textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  textureLoader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");

  map = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_COL_2K.jpg");
  //normal = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_NRM_2K.jpg");
  roughness = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_GLOSS_2K.jpg");
  //reflection = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_REFL_2K.jpg");
  displacement = textureLoader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/65874/WoodFlooring044_DISP_2K.jpg");

    // Create material
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: map,
    //normalMap: normal,
    //normalScale: new THREE.Vector2(30, -1),
    //roughnessMap: roughness,
    //reflectionMap: reflection,
    bumpMap: displacement,
    bumpScale: 100,
    //displacementBias: 0
    specularMap: roughness
  });
```

Comment: Ah you're right. I should have been using a StandardMeshMaterial in order to generate a physically based render.

Comment: While I still haven't been able to get a StandardMeshMaterial to work with a cube, I have had luck using PlaneGeometry: 

http://codepen.io/jpschwinghamer/pen/mWGKLE

I took your suggestion and boosted the contrast on the displacement map. I think in general wood textures are tough for webgl due to the minor variations in the texture.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about wood textures being tough for webgl. You always have the [custom shader option](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/wood_grain.html). Did you read the part about the normal map doing nothing?  Please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the BoxGeometry only contains 4 vertices per side. When you apply a displacement map, you actually move the positions of the vertices where a normal map would "fake" this on a fragment level.

To solve your problem, I would try with a geometry with a higher number of vertices. A sphere works fine for testing. Then import/generate a box geometry with more vertices.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He is using 10 segments `new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100, 10, 10, 10)`

Comment: Is 10 segments enough for this type of displacement?

Comment: no, not at all. For the texture that you are trying to use and it's very small variations, you would need an extreme amount of segments. Please see my answer regarding the textures.

Comment: My bad. But like @2pha also mentions, it can require alot of segments depending on the displacement map.